# Calling function from object in array (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have issues calling function "Izpis" from an array. Class below:

```
function Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka, stDelegatov) {
  if (ime == "" || priimek == "") {
    alert("Podatki niso popolni!");
    return;
  } else {
    this.ime = ime;
    this.priimek = priimek;
    this.stranka = stranka;
    this.id = polje.length + 1;
    this.stDelegatov = stDelegatov;
  }
  Izpis = function() {
    return "(" + this.id + ")" + this.ime + " " + this.priimek + " pripada stranki " + this.stranka + ".";
  }
  PosodobiIzpis = function(ime, priimek, stranka, stDelegatov) {
    this.ime = ime;
    this.priimek = priimek;
    this.stranka = stranka;
    this.stDelegatov = stDelegatov;
  }
}
```

I tried it like this:

```
var a = [];
a = a.concat(Isci($("#iskalniNiz")));
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var temp = (Kandidat)(a[i]).Izpis();
  $("br:eq(0)").after(temp + "\n");

}
```

and without (Kandidat) with no success. I am getting either "is undefined" or "is not a function" error.

Comment: What does function Isci() do?

Comment: this.Izpis did it for me.. I had no idea that object functions need that.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if `Kandidat` is meant to be a constructor function. The way you've defined `Izpis` is a bit sketchy...

If you want to make `Izpis` a property of an instance you're creating (using the `new` keyword), you need to write `this.Izpis`.

If you don't prefix it with `this.`, nor with `var`, it will do one of two things:

1. If there's a globally defined `Izpis`, it will overwrite this variable.
2. If there's no `Izpis` variable defined in the current context, it will create a new one inside the constructor function, which will not be accessible outside of this code block.

Another issue I see in your code, that might not initially show, is that you *are* using `this` inside the `Izpis` and `PosodobiIzpis` functions.

This will break once you call your functions other than `kandidatInstance.Izpis()`. E.g.: `setTimeout(kandidatInstance.Izpis)` will not work.

To fix this, do either:

```
function YourConstructor(id) {
  // Method 1: store 'this' context in closure
  var self = this;
  this.yourMethod = function() {
    return self.id;
  };

  // Method 2: explicitly bind 'this' context
  this.yourMethod2 = function() {
    return this.id;
  }.bind(this);
};

// Method 3: use prototype
YourConstructor.prototype.yourMethod3 = function() {
  return this.id;
};
```